# how to install android sdk tools (release 25.2.5) on ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: android, ubuntu, sdk, android-sdk-manager

I was trying to install SDK tools (tools_r25.2.5-linux) downloaded from follwing link https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.5-linux.zip  on my Linux Ubuntu 16.04.

I run both the following command for installation

```
./android update sdk
sudo ./android update sdk
```

but the installation is stopping and giving this error

[image: error]

also **~./android/androidtool.cfg** (both  **/root/.android** and **/home/user/.android** directory) file contains following data

```
http.proxyPort=proper_port
http.proxyHost=proper_proxy
sdkman.show.update.only=true
sdkman.ask.adb.restart=false
sdkman.force.http=true
```

what issue is causing the problem? how can i solve this?